# CORS issue while accessing AWS API from site hosted on S3 bucket

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cors

I am trying to populate my dynamodb from a form hosted on a S3 bucket. I am using a lambda function and an API gateway. It works fine when I test it there but when I try to POST data from my form, I get this error,

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yyyyyyy.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test' from origin 'http://xyz.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have enabled CORS on my API gateway. I have deployed it after enabling CORS.

I am using AJAX to POST. This s the function that executes when I click on a button on the form.

```
function submitToAPI(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var URL = "https://yx1wm602z6.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test";

       var name = $("#username").val();
       var desc = $("#desc").val();
       var diff=$("#difficulty").val();
       var dataa = {
        username : name,
          difficult:diff,
          desc : desc
        };

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "https://yyyyy.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test",
        
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         crossDomain: true,
         
         data: JSON.stringify(dataa),

         
         success: function (data) {
           
           alert("Successfull. Thank you for submitting");
           
         },
         error: function (e) {
           
           alert("UnSuccessfull"+JSON.stringify(e));
         }});
     }
```

My lambda function to populate DynamoDB in Python is as follows,

```
import boto3
import json


dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  username = event['username']

  difficult=event['difficult']
  desc=event['desc']
  
  
  dynamodb.put_item(TableName='users', Item={'username':{'S':username},'difficult' 
 {'S':'difficult'},'desc':{'S':desc}})
```

In my S3 bucket, I have added the CORS policy in the JSON format as XML is no longer supported.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://xyz.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Any kind of suggestions will definitely help me. I have been looking for solutions but nothing actually worked.

Comment: Why do you have two `lambda_handler` in your function?

Comment: @Marcin that was a mistake. I have edited the post. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a minute error. I had not specified the resource name in my API URL. Adding the URL worked out.
Would be nice if I got a better error response.